# Rails 4 - Rake aborted, Invalid CSS after AwesomeEotPath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, precompile

I am using the [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3), branch bootstrap 3. When I try to precompile my assets, rake is aborted due to what looks like an issue with fontawesome, which is included in the gem. Here is the error I get:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...AwesomeEotPath:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 'fontawesome-..."
  (in /Users/user/Code/Rails/ApplicationName/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):7153
```

I am able to precompile assets if I remove `require self` and `require_tree .` from the css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question almost immediately after posting it. All I needed to do was use `@import` instead of `*=` in the manifest file.